# What could be the better way here than to split the string in a loop?

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, object, split

I have a string:

```
FeatureName:Height-FeatureValue:1-vmin:1-max:20000-pricing-row-,
FeatureName:Width-FeatureValue:1-vmin:1-max:20000-pricing-row-,
FeatureName:ChannelCount-FeatureValue:23-vmin:234-max:0-pricing-row-,
FeatureName:Height-FeatureValue:1980-vmin:17-max:20000-pricing-row-,
FeatureName:Width-FeatureValue:230-vmin:234-max:987-pricing-row-
FeatureName:ChannelCount-FeatureValue:98-vmin:2834-max:0-pricing-row-
```

What is the best way possible to convert this string into an object that has 3 keys: `Height` , `Width` , `ChannelCount` and corresponding to each key, there are corresponding values, such as :

```
   Width => [
              {'FeatureValue' : 1 , 'vmin' : 1 , ...} , 
              {'FeatureValue' : 230 , 'vmin' : 234 , ...}
             ]
```

and so on for `Height` and `ChannelCount`.

I was trying to split the string, then run multiple loops and within the loop again splitting the string. What could be better way here? It will be best, if an approach with regex could be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting (ie parsing) this string by splitting it multiple times is not a bad solution.

However if you want to use regex, start by splitting your input into individual lines by splitting on ",".
Then for each line of your input, parse the line into its component pieces using this regex:

```
var s = 'FeatureName:Height-FeatureValue:1-vmin:1-max:20000-pricing-row-';
var ar = /([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.+)/.exec(s);
```

ar[1] through ar[5] contains the component pieces, e.g.:

```
  'FeatureName:Height',
  'FeatureValue:1',
  'vmin:1',
  'max:20000',
  'pricing-row-'
```

Optionally, this regex will further split each line into each of its component pieces:

```
var ar = /([^:]+):([^-]+)-([^:]+):([^-]+)-([^:]+):([^-]+)-([^:]+):([^-]+)-(.*)/.exec(s)
```

for instance:

```
'FeatureName',
  'Height',
  'FeatureValue',
  '1',
  'vmin',
  '1',
  'max',
  '20000',
  'pricing-row-',
```

Hopefully you can use these regexs to refine your solution.